# Reading how many lines the output file has

Tags: c, file-pointer

Here is my problem. The output file is seven lines, like this:

```
Dinda
Jane
is
so
beautiful
and
handsome.
```

We are asked to read how many lines the output file has. But two lines should count only 1. So, the exact number of lines in this program should be four (including the last one line). How am i supposed to read two lines at a time? This is what I got so far.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[25];
    char c[25][25];
    int a;

    clrscr();

    printf("Enter File Name: ");
    gets(filename);

    if(filename==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nERROR! File Doesn't Exist!");
    }
    else
    {
        fp=fopen(filename,"r");

        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            fgets(&c,sizeof(c),fp);
            printf("%s",c);
            if(strlen(c))
            {
                a++;
            }
        }

        printf("The Number of Words are: %d",a);
        fclose(fp);
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`. And the test `if(filename==NULL)` would never be true. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: Count number of lines using fgets and then print (n+1)/2 as result.

Comment: [`while(!feof(fp))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong/5432517#5432517) would be something you want to fix right now. It's wrong, and isn't helped by your assumption `fgets` *worked* with no verification checking at all.

Comment: You never specified in your question (and were likely never told in your assignment) whether each "line", including the *last* "line", *must* end with a newline char to be considered a complete "line". The last "line" of a file is often terminated *without* a newline, making line-counting algorithms more tedious to account for that special case than most first realize.

Comment: After thinking it over: what does "two lines should count only 1" mean? If the number of lines is odd, then you do *not* read two lines; you only read one. Therefore, logically it should *not* be counted.

Answer (score 1):

Why make it difficult(read 2 lines) when you do it simply like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[25];
    char buffer[256];
    int buffer_size = sizeof(buffer);
    int a=0;

    printf("Enter File Name: ");
    fgets(filename,sizeof(filename),stdin); //Always use fgets
    filename[strlen(filename)-1]='\0'; //Remove \n from the filename

    fp=fopen(filename,"r"); 
    if(fp==NULL) //Check if file pointer is NULL then return
    {
        printf("\nERROR! File Doesn't Exist!");
        return;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, buffer_size, fp)) //Count number of lines in file
    {
        a++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    //If number of lines are even then just divide by 2 else divide by 2 and add one
    if (a % 2 == 0) 
        a = (a / 2); 
    else        
        a = (a / 2) + 1;

    printf("The Number of lines are: %d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: Rather than the `if(a % 2 == 0)` block, just `a = a/2 + a%2;`.

Comment: @chux: Your suggestion is much better :) Thanks +1

Comment: Your `a % 2` idea though is a tad better than `a = (a+1)/2` as others have posted for the singular case when `a == INT_MAX`, your approach comes up with the correct answer.  IMO, `int` is too small for counting lines as files can be huge.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible solutions. Taking "read two lines at a time" literally, you would get

```
char c[256];
while(fgets (c, sizeof(c), fp)))
{
   a++;
   if (!fgets(c,sizeof(c),fp))
       break;
}
```

which reads a single line, increments the line counter, then reads another line *without* incrementing the counter. It will work correctly even if the last line does not end with a return (missing in your spec, but per WhozCraig's observation).

It can deal with single lines as long as 254 characters (excluding the terminating `\n`). You can adjust the code to allow longer lines than that: put both `fgets` commands inside a loop and break out of it if the last read character is an `\n` (or `fgets` returns `0` to indicate end of file or an error).

Comment: I initally copied parts from the OP :P The strange declaration of `char c[25][25];` threw me off, I missed the second part when fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
char c = getc(fp);
while (c != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') a++:
    c = getc(fp);
}

 printf("Number of line is %d", (a + 1)/2); // (the +1 is for the last line)
```

Comment: Note: Should use `int c`.  Otherwise 1 of the 256 different `char` will match `EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fp = fopen(filename,"r");
int flag = 0
ch = getc(fp)
while( ch != EOF)
{
    if( ch == '\n')
    {
        flag++;
    }
    ch = getc(fp);
}
flag = (flag+1)/2;
```

try this code in the else part of your code..

It gets one character at a time and compares if that is a newline character. it increments a flag variable if it is a new line character. in the end after all the characters in the file has been traversed. it will make the flag value half. just like u want it..